# Google App Engine downloadable and not downloadable blob items

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, blobstorage

i am a newbie in Google Web Toolkit and Google App Engine Technology so i need your help based on blobs. I am developing a web application for a company which needs to upload some files and serve them to their customers. The problem is that when someone uploads an item to the blobstore a url is created and whoever has that link can download/view the file but the specifications are the file to be downloaded to the user who have paid for that. Of course the user should be logged in before. So, how can i have some restrictions to the blob items and make them private to the prepaid customers?

Thanks in advance,
Stefanos Antaris

Comment: I have only developed the upload and download part of blobstorage into my application based on that [link](http://www.fishbonecloud.com/2010/12/tutorial-gwt-application-for-storing.html) blog.I guess that if i put some restrictions on the doGet method i will have my desired features but i am not totally sure. I have not found any relative post on the net either.This is why i am asking.

Comment: ok, I am not actually expert in this area - my speciality is Mathematica - but I know when a question is hard for potential answerers to figure out. I think you need to add some more information to your question to get a good answer from someone. This might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask. Incidentally, when I have bought software/pdfs etc from web sites, they often provide a special URL link just for that buyer, so that random people can't access the same link over and over to download the item. This might work in your case.

Comment: @Verbeia this is exactly what i need. I need to have special links for my blobstore items and those items to be visible/downloadable just from the user who have paid for.

Comment: ok, add that to your question, and think through how you might (1) generate the special URLs, (2) store them in a db of authorised special URLs and (3) only allow access to users using one of those special URLs that has not been used before (HINT - your db of URLs will need some sort of field for whether that one has been used before). Step through that and see if that suggests an approach. If it does and you work it out, post a comment, so that I can post it as an answer that you can accept.

Answer (score 1):

> The problem is that when someone uploads an item to the blobstore a
>   url is created and whoever has that link can download/view the file
>   but the specifications are the file to be downloaded to the user who
>   have paid for that.

That's not the case. The upload URL can only be used to upload the file, not to download it. If you use the image serving API, a URL is generated for your image that anyone can use, but that only happens if you explicitly call that API. Other than that, the only way to download a blob is if your app sets the correct header, as documented [here](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview.html#Serving_a_Blob).

Comment: I guess that it is the same for the java application.right?I will try it now.